# Not showing images in html

Tags: html, css, image

```css
body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flexbox{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
} 

nav{
    padding: 10px 2%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background: #fff;
    position: static;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}

.navright img{
    width: 25px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    

}

.navright .profile{
    width: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;

}

.navleft .menuicon{
    width: 25px;
}

.navleft .logo{
    width: 130px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.navmiddle .voice{
    
    width: 16px;
}

.navmiddle .search{
    
    width: 16px;
}

.navmiddle .searcharea{
    
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-right: 15px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    
}

.navmiddle .searchbox{
    width: 400px;
}

.sidebar{

    background: #fff;
    width: 15%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-top: 20px;
    z-index: -10;

}

.shortcuts a img{
    width: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}



.shortcuts a{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: fit-content;
    
    
}

.shortcuts a:first-child{
    color: red;
}

.sidebar hr{
    border: 0;
    width: 85%;
    height: 1px;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="flexbox">
        <div class="navleft flexbox">
            <img src="/images/menu.png" alt="" class="menuicon" >
            <img src="/images/logo.png" alt="" class="logo" >
        </div>
        <div class="navmiddle flexbox">
            <div class="searcharea">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="searchbox">
            <img src="/images/search.png" alt="" class="search" >
        </div>
        <img src="/images/voice-search.png" alt="" class="voice" >
        </div>
        <div class="navright">
            <img src="/images/upload.png" alt="" >
            <img src="/images/notification.png" alt="" >
            <img src="/images/simon.png" alt="" class="profile">
        </div>
    </nav>

    <!---sidebar-->

    <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="shortcuts">
            <a href=""><img src="images/home.png" alt="" srcset=""><p>Home</p></a>
            <a href=""><img src="images/explore.png" alt="" srcset=""><p>Explore</p></a>
            <a href=""><img src="images/subscriprion.png" alt="" srcset=""><p>Subscription</p></a>
            <a href=""><img src="images/library.png" alt="" srcset=""><p>Library</p></a>
            <a href=""><img src="images/history.png" alt="" srcset=""><p>History</p></a>
            <a href=""><img src="images/playlist.png" alt="" srcset=""><p>Playlist</p></a>
            <a href=""><img src="images/messages.png" alt="" srcset=""><p>Messages</p></a>
            <hr>
        </div>
        
        <div class="subscriptionlist">
            <h1>Subscription</h1>
            <a href=""><img src="images/tom.png" alt="" srcset=""><p>Tom Hardy</p></a>
            <a href=""><img src="images/Jack.png" alt="" srcset=""><p>Jack Nichol</p></a>
            <a href=""><img src="images/gerard.png" alt="" srcset=""><p>Gerard Pique</p></a>
            <a href=""><img src="images/megan.png" alt="" srcset=""><p>Megan Steve </p></a>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hello i am trying to replicate youtube.I am coding for the side bar. I added 4 images for sidebar under the class name .subscriptionlist.But the problem is only 1 image is showing in the browser
the image which has a filename of tom is showing. Rest of the three images are not showing in browser. Kindly help me to fix this.

Comment: you are missing a / in your images src: `<img src="/images/home.png"`

Comment: Or you can add the <base href=""> tag to prevent having to fix each image tags

Comment: i added "/" still not working

Answer (score 0):

```css
.sidebar{
position: relative;
}
```

change position